# Replace xml node in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, xsd

This is my xml code

```
<RuleDTO xsi:type="DefaultRuleDTO">
    <RuleID>0</RuleID> 
    <Priority xsi:nil="true" /> 
    <CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreationDate> 
    <Status>false</Status> 
    <USBStatus>false</USBStatus> 
    <PolicyID>0</PolicyID> 
    <EnfroceUserRule>true</EnfroceUserRule> 
    <DefaultRule>false</DefaultRule> 
</RuleDTO>
```

Here is another xml code

```
<RuleDTO xsi:type="SizeRuleDTO">
    <RuleID>23</RuleID> 
    <RuleName>test</RuleName> 
    <Description>sdf</Description> 
    <Priority xsi:nil="true" /> 
    <CreatedBy>administrator</CreatedBy> 
    <CreationDate>2012-03-27T03:18:19</CreationDate> 
    <Status>true</Status> 
    <USBStatus>false</USBStatus> 
    <PolicyID>5</PolicyID> 
    <Size>4</Size> 
</RuleDTO>
<RuleDTO xsi:type="DefaultRuleDTO">
    <RuleID>0</RuleID> 
    <Priority xsi:nil="true" /> 
    <CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreationDate> 
    <Status>false</Status> 
    <USBStatus>false</USBStatus> 
    <PolicyID>0</PolicyID> 
    <EnfroceUserRule>true</EnfroceUserRule> 
    <DefaultRule>false</DefaultRule> 
</RuleDTO>
```

Here I want to replace first code with second code with specific node and sub node.

How I can change it?

Comment: @L.B i want to replace that specific part with new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
        xmlDoc2.Load(xmlFile2);


        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Root/RuleDTO/RuleID");
        XmlNode node2 = xmlDoc2.SelectSingleNode("Root/RuleDTO[1]/RuleID");
        XmlNode node3 = xmlDoc2.SelectSingleNode("Root/RuleDTO[2]/RuleID");

        if (node != null && node2 != null && node3 != null)
            node3.InnerText = node2.InnerText = node.InnerText;

        xmlDoc2.Save(xmlFile2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
XElement first = ...
XElement second = ...

first.ReplaceWith(second);
```